# Ancient Roman Slang

Tags: ancient-rome, latin-language

Is anyone able to recommend a book or website which lists slang from Ancient Rome?

As an example, how would a Roman say the equivalent of "it's screwed up"?  There are many ways of saying this in English: "it's gone tits up", "it all went pear-shaped" and so on.  However, as far as I can see the Romans would not have used the word for sex in this particular expression, as we do.

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Buffy, first, welcome to [history.se]! Next, I respectfully ask that you take a quick look at [help/on-topic]. In it you might notice that in the _it is not about_ section is _requests for reference_. Believe it or not, we have chosen not to offer up recommendations of resources or sources.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would still be grateful if someone has any ideas about how an ancient Roman might have phrased this particular piece of slang.

Comment: Thats not a history question, thats a linguistic question.

Comment: It says in the help centre that CG Campbell directed me to that it is OK to ask questions about Ancient Languages.

Comment: You might want to think again.  The Romans had a rich tradition of scatalogical and sex based abuse for use when called for.

Comment: You will get a better answer at wordreference.com in the "Latin" forum.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone.  I will post on wordreference.com.

Comment: Holy Sh*t: A Brief History of Swearing by Melissa Mohr